# Box2d cannot cast to void*

Tags: c++, box2d

https://www.iforce2d.net/b2dtut/collision-callbacks

I am referencing this site to implement a crash listener. But while implementing BeginContact I get the following error: The result of getUserDate() cannot be cast to void* type.

```
void BeginContact(b2Contact* contact)
{
    void* data = contact->GetFixtureA()->GetBody()->GetUserData(); //error!!
}
```

Comment: For me it compiles without error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is because latest Box2D release by Erin Cato changed the return type from previous releases from returning a [`void*`](https://github.com/erincatto/box2d/blob/v2.4.0/include/box2d/b2_body.h#L382) to returning [`b2BodyUserData&`](https://github.com/erincatto/box2d/blob/master/include/box2d/b2_body.h#L379). The [definition of the latter being](https://github.com/erincatto/box2d/blob/v2.4.1/include/box2d/b2_settings.h#L58):

```
struct B2_API b2BodyUserData
{
    b2BodyUserData()
    {
        pointer = 0;
    }

    /// For legacy compatibility
    uintptr_t pointer;
};
```

(which won't implicitly convert to `void*`).